# servlet/jsp spec for various web servers

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

According to this table [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), it is easy to see which tomcat version adheres to which servlet/jsp specs.

Does anyone know where to find similar information for WebSphere Application Server (I am interested in versions 6 and 7), JBoss AS (versions 4.2, 5.1 and 6) and WebLogic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [application server comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_application_servers#Java_EE) wiki page is a good place to start, but it typically only lists the newest version (although it does provide links to vendor sites which may be helpful).

Also, WAS 6 was servlet 2.4, JSP 2.0.  Not sure about JBoss.